# Should i expect to execute of 160billion iteration from oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have a table that contains approximately 390 000 records and up to now I found 3 different algorithm(solution) for my problem. Each algorithm require cartesian product of table with itself.
I am wondering only that; should i expect from oracle 11g to execute a query requires 160 Billion iteration or what? Because for one week I try a lot of things but whatever I do it is not end even after 8 hour execution.

If this is normal for this much process I maybe start thinking of a new algorithm because I must ended up in approximately 30 minutes.

My last and better among three algorithm is;

```
declare
loopCount number(10);
remainingRows number(10);
dup number(10);
crosses number(10);
res varchar2(5);--TRUE or FALSE
BEGIN
loopCount :=0;
remainingRows :=0;
crosses :=0;
dup := 0;
res :='FALSE';
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO remainingRows FROM ORAHAN;--376497 records
WHILE(remainingRows ^= 0) LOOP
 FOR aRow IN (SELECT mip,startmi,mi_prinx,geoloc,rownum FROM ORAHAN where rownum=1)  LOOP
  FOR bRow IN (SELECT mip,startmi,mi_prinx,geoloc FROM ORAHAN WHERE Mi_Prinx ^= aRow.Mi_Prinx) LOOP
    BEGIN
      --loopCount := loopCount+1;
      select SDO_GEOM.RELATE(aRow.geoloc,'anyinteract', bRow.Geoloc,0.02) into res from dual;
      IF (res='TRUE') THEN
        Insert INTO ORAHANCROSSES values (aRow.Mip,aRow.Startmi,bRow.Mip,bRow.Startmi);
        DELETE FROM ORAHAN WHERE MI_PRINX=bRow.MI_PRINX;
        COMMIT;
        crosses := crosses+1;
        END IF;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
          dup := dup+1;
    END;
    remainingRows := remainingRows-1;
  END LOOP;
DELETE FROM ORAHAN WHERE MI_PRINX=aRow.MI_PRINX;
END LOOP;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO remainingRows FROM ORAHAN;
END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line('crosses: ' || crosses);
dbms_output.put_line('duplicate: ' || dup);
END;
```

I execute this and in 3 hour it is delete 604 record from source table and insert 99 row to target table. There is 376342 remaining rows.

Comment: Let's say that each row is 1 kb.  So 390,000 rows is about 390 MB.  A Cartesian product produces 160 billion rows each 2 kb in size.  That's about 283 PB of data.  Even if each row is just a couple dozen bytes, that's still PB of data.  Does your server even have enough disk to theoretically be able to materialize a result set that size let alone to do so in a reasonably efficient manner?  If you've given Oracle multiple PB of RAM and thousands of PB of solid state disk, you're going to have much better luck than if you gave it a few GB of RAM.  But I suspect your algorithm could be improved.

Comment: What Justin said. Or you may be mistaken in thinking that the server will actually perform a Cartesian product. The optimiser might be smart enough to figure out a way to avoid it. Without seeing your algorithms it's impossible to be sure, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use SDO_RELATE function which is very fast against SDO_GEOM_RELATE. But SDO_REALTE has no parameter as buffer. We use SDO_GEOM.SDO_BUFFER for giving 2cm buffer to the target object. Now it takes one hour for intersection all records with each other. 
Here is working code;

```
BEGIN
for curs in (select * from ORAHAN t) loop
 for curs2 in (select *
           from ORAHAN t2
          where SDO_RELATE(t2.geoloc,SDO_GEOM.SDO_BUFFER(curs.geoloc,0.2,0.02,'UNIT=M') , 
          'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
            and t2.mi_prinx <> curs.mi_prinx) loop                    
  Insert INTO ORAHANCROSSES
   values
   (curs.Mip, curs.Startmi, curs2.Mip, curs2.Startmi);
  commit;
 end loop;
end loop;
END;
```